# Wordpress Background image with URL link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have these code from my wordpress theme, i want my background image to have a link to other website

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (class_exists('BlackfyreMultiPostThumbnails')) : $custombck = BlackfyreMultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'header-image', $post->ID, 'full' ); endif; ?>
<?php if(empty($custombck)){}else{ ?>
<style>
    body.page{
    background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url($custombck) ; ?>) !important;
    background-position:center top !important;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat !important;
}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be suitable:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<style>
    BODY.enterPage{
    cursor:hand;
}
</style>
<script>
   function goto(){
       location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
   }
</script>
</head>
<body class="enterPage"  onclick="goto();">
    <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Enter</a>
</body>
</html>
```

From [this forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=381087)

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know where to put that codes you gave, I've posted a part of the .php codes from wordpress, and i think i can change it there,

by the way its a custom theme

Comment: @JerichoMorales You can not use this code directly, It is written to give you idea .

Comment: @JerichoMorales in your header.php add onclick="goto();" on body and in rest of code in head section.Then give your url !

Comment: @RizwanTaj tried it, but the problem is almost all of the body has a link, not only the background image